# How to count the distinct member at every time window in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I have table like this which represent a member bought a product in a month. The month is from 201501 to 201612. 
I want to get a new table which contains two columns: one is the month from 201501 to 201612 and the other is the count(distinct member_srl) as member_rolling, which is from the previous 12 months' records at that month.
For example, one record of new table is "201605  123456", the number 123456 is the count(distinct member_srl) on the condition of month >= '201505' and month < '201605'.
So how to realize this in a simple way and fast way?

```
member_srl  month
21197731    201501
14353419    201509
42129336    201605
10599714    201611
16162595    201501
50487249    201601
14899586    201604
29611434    201607
15374407    201608
14479686    201501
1621671     201502
20814896    201512
8185190     201501
57833156    201601
5215620     201503
60407250    201602
3510594     201501
25221577    201611
2120126     201512
```

Answer (score 0):

You should join the table with itself.
Join it on the month column with your desired 12 months range.
Then do your aggregation on the relevant column.
Something like:
`SELECT t1.id AS id, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.member_srl) AS member_srl_distinct_count
FROM test t1 JOIN test t2 
ON t1.id= t2.id OR t1.id=(t2.id-1) OR t1.id=(t2.id-2) ...
GROUP BY t1.id;`

In this example I use an INT column (id) as your month column, so you'll need to cast your month column to date in order to be able to add/substract months to it